# Issue with access a variables value outside of a function

Tags: javascript

```
let dark = true;
function toggle() {
    dark = false;
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
}

if (dark = false) {
    document.getElementById("logo").src="../../img/Kevin D (White).png";
}else {
    document.getElementById("logo").src="../../img/Kevin D (Black).png";
}
```

Above is my code. Whenever I click the button the image does not go to the white version, instead it just stays black even on a black background, how would I fix this? The code is also attached to a button which would call that function

Comment: Just because your variable changes doesn't mean the if statement is re-run (also, your `if` is using an assignment `=` not a comparison `==` or `===`)

Comment: Thats the problem. The variable doesn't change

Comment: If I set dark to true in the if statement, the problem would reverse

Comment: If you call `toggle()` then the variable will change. The problem is your `if` statement, you need to wrap it in a function and call it when the variable changes (and also use a comparison not and assignment)

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: What you don't show is when/how `toggle()` gets called, or when/how your if-statement gets run. I would expect the `if (dark === false)` to be _**in**_ the toggle function, right after `document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');` — Separately, you can just test `if (dark)` or `if (!dark)`

Comment: It gets called through a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to solve here:

- You need to call the `if` again when the variable changes, we do this by wrapping it in a function, then calling it on load and whenever the toggle is called.
- Toggle currently doesn't "toggle", set the value to `!dark` to invert it every time.
- The `if` is currently assigning the value `false` to the `dark` variable, we need to compare it instead, and since it's already a boolean, it can simply be `if (dark) {}`

```js
var dark = true;

function toggle() {
  dark = !dark; // To actually toggle the variable you need to invert the current value
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
  // After the variable is toggle, call the function to update the theme
  changeTheme()
}

function changeTheme() {
  if (dark) {
    console.log("It's dark!")
  } else {
    console.log("It's light!")
  }
}

// Call the function on load to set the initial theme
changeTheme()

// Add an event listener to call the toggle function
document.getElementById("toggle").addEventListener("click", toggle);
```

```html
<div id="toggle">Toggle</div>
```

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error with the = sign. It should be ==

```
if (dark == false) {
```

Comment: The variable is already defined outside of the function?

Comment: It is outside of the function

Comment: I've used both. Both do not work.

Answer (score 1):

- Your function is called 'toggle' but at the moment would only set dark to false. So I would change that to `dark = !dark`, so it's always setting to the opposite.
- Next step is to include the if-else block inside the function, so it is executed when toggling.
- The single equal sign in the if statement was already mentioned...
- instead of `if(dark === false)` you can simply check `if(!dark)` or better swap the logic to not begin with a negation and say `if(dark){'dark'}else{'not dark}`
- It looks like you have blanks inside the filenames of the images, which might be probably better avoided...

```js
let dark = true;

function toggle() {

  dark = !dark;
  
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');

  if (dark === false) {
    console.log('dark ===', dark, '>> set white img')
    // document.getElementById("logo").src = "../../img/Kevin D (White).png";
  } else {
    console.log('dark ===', dark, '>>set black img')
    // document.getElementById("logo").src = "../../img/Kevin D (Black).png";
  }
}
```

```css
.dark-mode {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little mistake. Instead of = have to use ==. And put the if condition inside the toggle function.

```js
let dark = true;
function toggle() {
    dark = false;
    document.body.classList.toggle('dark-mode');
    if (dark == false) {
      document.getElementById("logo").src="../../img/Kevin D (White).png";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("logo").src="../../img/Kevin D (Black).png";
    }
}

console.log(dark)
toggle();
console.log(dark)
```

Comment: I've just ran this. Problem persists

Comment: @KevinD you have to commented out everthing in the if condition.  in the console you will see that change between true to false.

Answer (score 0):

It because you don't re-run scr assignee when your source data change. For that reason exist frameworks like react, vue.... etc. . You don't have any code which would observer changes and prepper some view update. Your data is not bind to view.

Easy to adapt and build in browser observer implementations is Event Target. You can extend this object and add possibility to observer events on it.

```js
class Theme extends EventTarget {
  _mode = 'dark';
  
  set mode(value){
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    this._mode = value;
  }
  
  get mode(){
    return this._mode;
  }
}

const theme = new Theme();

theme.addEventListener('change', (event) =>{
  console.log('now addapt to chnaged', event.target.mode)
  //document.getElementById("logo").src="../../img/Kevin D (White).png"
})

function toggle(){
  theme.mode = theme.mode === "dark" ? "white" : "dark";
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle</>
```